# MongoDB aggregation and group by id and then date

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

My `audit_records` collections is as below :

```
{u'policy_holder': u'Kapil', u'_id': ObjectId('4d663451d1e7242c4b68e000'),  u'audit_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 6, 10, 5, 12, 474000), u'policy_ids':    [u'92b7bbfa-688e9e5304d5'], u'category': u'TIManagement'}
{u'policy_holder': u'Sunil', u'_id': ObjectId('4d6634514cb5cb2c4b69e000'),  u'audit_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 6, 11, 5, 12, 474000), u'policy_ids': [u'92b7bbfa-688e9e5304d5'], u'category': u'PIManagement'}
{u'policy_holder': u'Edward', u'_id': ObjectId('4d6634514cb5cb2c4b65e000'),  u'audit_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 3, 12, 4, 2, 723000), u'policy_ids': [u'92b7ccge-688e9e5304d5'], u'category': u'TIManagement'}
```

I'm querying my database using aggregation and pipeline to group by `policy_ids` and no of `policy_holder` associated with that `policy_ids` 
and my code is as below:

```
startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime("2015-01-06",'%Y-%m-%d')
enddate = datetime.datetime.strptime("2015-10-01",'%Y-%m-%d')

pipe = [{'$match':{"audit_time": {"$gt": startdate,"$lte": enddate}}},{'$group': {'_id': '$policy_ids', 'policy_holder': {'$sum': 1}}}]

for data in db.audit_records.aggregate(pipeline=pipe):
```

Out got :

```
{u'policy_holder': 2, u'_id': u'92b7bbfa-688e9e5304d5'}
{u'policy_holder': 1, u'_id': u'92b7ccge-688e9e5304d5'}
```

Now want to group this whole output by date, is it possible and how?

Comment: you wants to group by date ?

Comment: Yes , first group by policy_ids and then date.

Basically all I want is to list  no of policy ids, and count of policy_holder for that policy id for a given date. How do i achieve this

Comment: Group by date how? The dates are individual items on each document, so which one gets picked in the first grouping procedure? First? Last? Mininum? Maximum? And then group by date what? Presumably "day"?

Comment: Yes group by day. Per day how many policy present and count of policy holder for each  policy.

Comment: you wants like  select policy_id, day , count(policy_no) from table group by ploicy_id, day

Comment: Yes. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the aggregation pipeline with $unwind with group

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind:"$policy_ids"},{$group:{_id:{policy_id:"$policy_ids",audit_time:"$audit_time"},sum:{$sum:1}}}])
```

> **I Modify a bit in your document**
>
> Inserted the document like this

```
{'policy_holder': 'Kapil', '_id': ObjectId('4d663451d1e7242c4b68e000'),  'audit_time': new Date(2015, 9, 6, 10, 5, 12, 474000), 'policy_ids':    ['92b7bbfa-688e9e5304d5'], 'category': 'TIManagement'}
{'policy_holder': 'Sunil', '_id': ObjectId('4d6634514cb5cb2c4b69e000'),  'audit_time': new Date(2015, 9, 6, 11, 5, 12, 474000), 'policy_ids': ['92b7bbfa-688e9e5304d5'], 'category': 'PIManagement'}
{'policy_holder': 'Edward', '_id': ObjectId('4d6634514cb5cb2c4b65e000'),  'audit_time': new Date(2015, 8, 3, 12, 4, 2, 723000), 'policy_ids': ['92b7ccge-688e9e5304d5'], 'category': 'TIManagement'}
```

> Update the Aggregation Query

```
db.policy.aggregate([{$unwind:"$policy_ids"},{$group:{_id:{"policy":"$policy_ids",day: { $dayOfYear: "$audit_time"}, year: { $year: "$audit_time" }},total:{$sum:1}}}])
```

**

> Output is

**

{ "_id" : { "policy" : "92b7ccge-688e9e5304d5", "day" : 246, "year" : 2015 }, "total" : 1 }

{ "_id" : { "policy" : "92b7bbfa-688e9e5304d5", "day" : 279, "year" : 2015 }, "total" : 2 }

Hope this is you are expecting

Comment: It will not give me list something like this :

     Date                 policy_ids                        Policy_holder count
     2015-09,06    92b7bbfa-688e9e5304d5   2

Comment: what the output it's giving ? can you paste it here ?

Comment: Here is the output 

      {u'sum': 1, u'_id': {u'audit_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 6, 10, 5, 12, 474000), u'policy_ids': u'92b7bbfa-688e9e5304d5'}}

     {u'sum': 1, u'_id': {u'audit_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 22, 5, 3, 7, 724000), u'policy_ids': u'92b7bbfa-688e9e5304d5'}}      

     {u'sum': 1, u'_id': {u'audit_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 3, 12, 4, 2, 723000), u'policy_ids': u'92b7ccge-688e9e5304d5'}}